# Why isn't DAX allowing the '==' operator?

Tags: excel, dax

Documentation confirms the existence of the '==' (strictly equal to) operator.
However, I get the "The syntax for '=' is incorrect. (DAX(IF([col] == 0, 1, 0))) error message.

Just to be clear I am trying to create a calculated column in the formula bar in the "data model", not in the Power Query editor (which uses M language instead of DAX IIUC).

Ultimately, I want to distinguish 0's from blank cells with an IF([col] == 0,,)

Running Excel Office 365 for Enterprises Version 2104 on Windows 10.

Comment: You can differentiate blanks and zeros: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756571/powerbi-differentiate-blank-value-and-0-value/51757866#51757866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some differences in DAX for Excel's PowerPivot and DAX in Power BI. The documentation for the `==` operator does not mention this, but it only works in Power BI, not in PowerPivot for Excel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll have a look into Power BI then, a quick Google search showed me I don't even really know what it is. Thank you for the enlightment